# Slide the off canvas menu back after a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the Jansy Off Canvas menu ([found here](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas)) for a site I'm currently working on. I got the menu to slide out, and it slides back if you click the burger menu again. But would I would like it to do is slide back off if the user also clicks one of the links. Right now it just remains out.

i tried to use this code:

```
$(".navbar-toggle").unbind().on("click", function () {
        console.log("toggle");
        $("#myNavmenu a").offcanvas("hide")
    });
```

But it only gets fired if the burger menu is clicked.

This is what the burger menu looks like in my HTML:

```
    <!-- burger menu -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="burgerWrapper">
             <nav id="myNavmenu" class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden"><a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#criminalLaw" class="page-scroll">CRIMINAL LAW</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#criminalLocalCourt" class="page-scroll">LOCAL COURT MATTERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#criminalMentalHealth" class="page-scroll">SECTION 32 APPLICATIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#criminalConviction" class="page-scroll">CONVICTION AND SEVERITY APPEALS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#criminalPenalties" class="page-scroll">INDICTABLE MATTERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#criminalFee" class="page-scroll">FEE ARRANGEMENTS</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#myNavmenu" data-canvas="body">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end burger menu -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code below will solve your issue.

```js
$(".nav li a").click(function (){
    
  $('#myNavmenu').offcanvas("hide");

});
```